# How to view datas in classes via Ocamldebug?

Tags: ocaml, ocamldebug

I'm using OCamldebug to debug OCaml program of version 4.01.0. Just as debug info followed, the debugger breaks at line 61(where indicated as "<|b|>"). When i was trying to view data inside class "re". The debugger just print the type info instead of giving any tips for the class.

```
(ocd) list
51         re#adjust_jmpref il'
52         (* |> re#add_func_label u_fl *)
53         |> cfg#visit
54       in
55 
56       let fbl = cfg#get_fbl in
57       let bbl = cfg#get_bbl in
58       let cfg_t = cfg#get_cfg_table il' in
59       let cg = cg#get_cg_table in
60       let il = re#add_bblock_label bbl il' in
61       (<|b|>fbl, bbl, cfg_t, cg, il, re)
62 
63 
64     let post_analyze il re =
65      ( re#unify_loc il
66        |> pp_print_list
67        |> re#adjust_globallabel @@ global_bss ()
68        |> pp_print_file);
69 
70   end
Position out of range.
(ocd) print self
Unbound identifier self
(ocd) print re
re:
  < add_bblock_label : Type.bblock list -> Type.instr list -> 'a;
    adjust_jmpref : 'b -> Type.instr list; adjust_loclabel : 'c -> 'b;
    reassemble_dump : Type.func list -> 'd; share_lib_processing : 'e -> 'c;
    visit_type_infer_analysis : 'f list -> Type.instr list -> 'e; .. >
  = <obj>
(ocd) print re#instr
Unbound identifier
```

Part of definition of Class re is as followed.(about 2300 lines of codes).

```
class reassemble =

  let data_set = Hashtbl.create 200
  and plt_hash = Hashtbl.create 50
  and pic_hash = Hashtbl.create 3
  and text_set = Hashtbl.create 30 in

  object(self)
    inherit ailVisitor

    val mutable label : (string*int) list = []
    (* collect relocation info in c2d *)
    val mutable c2d_addr: int list = []
    val mutable deslist: string list = []
    (* only collect the relocated symbol *)
    val mutable deslist_reloc: int list = []
    val mutable init_array_list: string list = []
    val mutable eh_frame_list: string list = []
    val mutable excpt_tbl_list: string list = []
    val mutable jmpreflist: string list = []
    val mutable sec : section list = []
    val mutable instr_list: instr list = []
    val mutable text_sec: (int*int) = (0,0)  (* begin addr, size*)
    val mutable plt_sec: (int*int) = (0,0)  (* begin addr, size*)
    val mutable text_mem_addrs: string list = []
```

And i've tried a demo file for OCamldebug and error still occurred.
[image: error]
I'm sure that i'm trying to print the correct identifiers of the class members. I didn't find any help in OCamldebug help info. What should i do if i'd like to view data inside classes?

Comment: In the printed representation of that object, I don't see any thing by the name `instr`. None of the  instance member has this name, so why are we trying to access `instr` on `re` object? can you please, also include the `class definition` of `re`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan i could confirm that i used the correct names and i've tried to print other identifiers such as `label`, `sec`, etc. But i got the same error.

Comment: Things accessible that way have to be a `method`.

Comment: @NalinRanjan So that means i can never get access to the data member of classes, right? methods are codes which can be viewed in source files, isn't it? And "Syntax error" occured again when i tried to access methods of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set up a [demo](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) and see how its behaving...

```ml
class a_demo_class = 
  object (self)
    val inaccessible_val: string = "Hello"
      
    method accessible_method: string = "Hello"
  end ;;
  
  
let demo = new a_demo_class;;

demo#accessible_method;;
demo#inaccessible_val;; (* This errors*)
```

The second access throws...

```ml
Error: This expression has type a_demo_class
It has no method inaccessible_val
```

Comment: i got the same syntax error when i was trying to get access to `demo#accessible_method` in OCamldebug.

Comment: can you try a `print *` command, keeping the debugger on the breakpoint of the identifier to be watched?

Comment: I am sure you would have come across [Examining Variable Values](https://ocaml.org/manual/debugger.html#s%3Adebugger-examining-values) section...

Comment: It just print out `$2: string = "Hello"`, which is the value just evaluated. And it doesn't give me any help for watching members in class.

Comment: Member access notation isn't working inside `debugger`. can you do a workaround, evaluate the members of the class inside local bindings and try to access those as they become simple expression as per that documentation link. For example, `let watch_accessible = demo#accessible_method` and then in the debugger do `display watch_accessible`... can you try that out please?

Comment: It does not work either. I add `let test = demo#accessible_method;;` to the end of the demo. And got `Unidentified value test` again.

Comment: strange... I can see... `(ocd) display test
test: string = "Hello"`

Comment: By the way, I am running the debugger inside emacs... where are you running it?

Comment: did you do a clean rebuild?

Comment: eh... I just ran it in terminal. Because i'm not very familar with the key binding options in emacs. And i build the demo with command `ocamlc -g test.ml -o test` and debug the binary with command `ocamldebug test`.

Comment: Is there any probablity that ocamldebug for old version of ocaml do not support that kind of operations?